# Airflow: Increase Airflow Task Timeout time

Tags: airflow

I'm hitting some issues where a few of my tasks are timing out. When the task reruns, or I retry the task, it works fine.

Is there a way to increase the time out either in the config, or within the DAG itself to avoid these errors?

```
ERROR - Process timed out
ERROR - Failed to import: /home/ec2-user/airflow/dags/dse/mydag.py

airflow.exceptions.AirflowTaskTimeout: Timeout
    
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: dag_id could not be found: mydag. Either the dag did not exist or it failed to parse.
```

Comment: Can you please share your process code?